# CPrintDialog Creation Failing in Service Mode of an Application

Tags: printing, mfc, visual-c++-6

I have an application that prints the report automatically. I am using CPrintDialog to get the Printer DC.

```
void CMyClass::PrintReport()
{
    CDC dc;
    CPrintDialog printDlg(FALSE);
    printDlg.GetDefaults ();
    ::DeleteDC( printDlg.m_pd.hDC );
    LPDEVMODE pDevMode = printDlg.GetDevMode();
    if(pDevMode)
    {
        pDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
        ::GlobalUnlock(pDevMode);
    }
    HDC hDC;
    if( (hDC = printDlg.CreatePrinterDC()) == NULL )
    {
        ::GlobalFree( printDlg.m_pd.hDevMode );
        ::GlobalFree( printDlg.m_pd.hDevNames );
        return;
    }
    ::GlobalFree( printDlg.m_pd.hDevMode );
    ::GlobalFree( printDlg.m_pd.hDevNames );
    dc.Attach(hDC);         // Attach a printer DC
    dc.m_bPrinting = TRUE;
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
    /* 

        Printing Logic using dc
    */
}
```

This works fine when I run my application in the Debug mode which comes a a Console application.

But, the CPrintDialog creation is failing when I run the application as a Windows Service.

Am I doing anything wrong? :( Please help me.

Note: The Application is designed in a way to run as a Service in the Installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the CPrintDialog creation is failing when I run the application as a Windows Service.

You cannot display dialogs (or any type of user interface) in a Windows Service. So `CPrintDialog` is never going to work.

But you don't need to create a dialog to get a printer device context, assuming that you already know which printer you want to print to. And since you're running as a non-interactive service, you *must* already know this, because there's no way that the user can choose a printer.

To do so, just call [`CreateDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183490.aspx) directly, specifying `"WINSPOOL"` as the device and the name of the printer. You can obtain the name of the desired printer by enumerating the installed printers using the [`EnumPrinters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692.aspx) function. This is all conveniently documented in a how-to article: [Retrieve a Printer Device Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Cody Gray :) But can I use the GetDefaultPrinter() in VC6

Comment: @jmaniac `GetDefaultPrinter` retrieves the printer name of the default printer for the current user. If you are running from a service, there is no *current user*. You might be able to use it with VC6, but you cannot ever use it from a service.

Comment: What you're probably using it from is a very old version of Windows, one that predates the security architecture changes implemented with Windows Vista, and it's just a coincidence that you're running an old version of Visual C++ on that older version of Windows. (Although this doesn't explain everything. Even in early versions of NT, when there was no user logged in, there was no current user, making that function meaningless. So it probably just *appeared* to work, because when you were testing it you were logged in.)

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray.. So I cant get the Default Printer through the EnumPrinters() and the logic you mentioned when I run that as a service. Right?