# GetDefaultPrinter() reference unfound in VC6

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, printing, mfc, visual-c++-6

As per the suggestion for the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211832/cprintdialog-creation-failing-in-service-mode-of-an-application) I am trying to use the GetDefaultPrinter() and then to the CreateDC(), but the VC6 is consistently saying

```
error C2065: 'GetDefaultPrinter' : undeclared identifier
```

I tried Google but many faced the same problem, but none of them were fruitful. Is this a correct way to use the GetDefaultPrinter().

Winspool.h and Windows.h are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a very old SDK. Check if `GetDefaultPrinter` is defined in your winspool.h file. If not, here are the definitions:

```
BOOL
WINAPI
GetDefaultPrinterA (
    LPSTR pszBuffer,
    LPDWORD pcchBuffer
    );
BOOL
WINAPI
GetDefaultPrinterW (
    LPWSTR pszBuffer,
    LPDWORD pcchBuffer
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetDefaultPrinter  GetDefaultPrinterW
#else
#define GetDefaultPrinter  GetDefaultPrinterA
#endif // !UNICODE

BOOL
WINAPI
SetDefaultPrinterA (
    LPCSTR pszPrinter
    );
BOOL
WINAPI
SetDefaultPrinterW (
    LPCWSTR pszPrinter
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetDefaultPrinter  SetDefaultPrinterW
#else
#define SetDefaultPrinter  SetDefaultPrinterA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael :) I have installed with the Latest Win SDK 7.1 but how to use it in VC6?

Comment: You can't use the latest SDKs with VC6. The latest SDK for VC6 is from 2003. Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e1147034-9b0b-4494-a5bc-6dfebb6b7eb1/download-and-install-microsoft-platform-sdk-febuary-2003-last-version-with-vc6-support?forum=windowssdk).