# How to Print a File(HTML File) from a Windows Service based MFC Application?

Tags: visual-c++, service, printing, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am having my Application to be run as a Windows Service with 'Local System' Account. It is being developed in VC6.

The Application needs to print a HTML File generated inside. The HTML File will be written onto the Disk and then to Print.

Will the [CHtmlView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h6dke4.aspx) and associated class can help in this implementation?

Will the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) be able to run from a Service?

As per one of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211832/cprintdialog-creation-failing-in-service-mode-of-an-application) and its answer the application now using the [EnumPrinters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and associated Windows APIs to get and print the MFC based Reports.

Is there any way to send the generated HTML/RTF File directly to the Printer?